# C++ templates interfaces using

Tags: c++, templates

I found template interfaces very elegant, and trying implementing it faced problem that I can't solve. I hope you can shed some light on it for me.

I have class, for example, *forge.h*:

```
template<typename T> class Smelter;

template <typename T>
class Forge
{
    long SmeltIt(vector<T>& ore)
    {
        long res;
        Smelter<T> smelter;  
        for (const auto t : ore)
        {
            res += smelter.smelt(t);
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

With template class Smelter without any realization and template class Forge with realization.

Now, when I want to add class Iron, I need to create iron.h and implement Smelter to use it, this way *iron.h*:

```
#include "forge.h"
class Iron {};

template<>
class Smelter<Iron>
{
    long smelt(const Iron& iron) { return 5; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Iron> ore;
    Iron iron;
    ore.push_back(iron);
    ore.push_back(iron);
    ore.push_back(iron);
    Forge<Iron> forge;
    cout << forge.SmeltIt(ore); //have to be 15
}
```

If all this stuff is in **one** header file, everything perfectly works. But if I create *iron.h* where I try to implement Smelter, compiler can't find template class Smelter. If I create copy of declaration for Smelter in both forge.h and iron.h, then they conflict with each other.

What is the best solution for that? It would be very useful if I would be able to realize my template interface in other files. Without this such template interfaces becomes ugly, for example, if *forge.h* is tools, wirely used between projects, and *iron.h* is my current specialization.

**RESULT:**
Everything works as expected, problem was outside of described question, in namespaces. All templates, even if it is possible to separate them between different files (that was question) - perfectly works. But they have to share same namespaces.

Comment: I fixed the code errors. Could you please show the errors your compiler outputs when you use 2 files ?

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing code errors (I wrote it directly here), and for ask to show the errors. When I started to change question adding there errors, I found where was my mistake. It was very silly mistake with namespaces. Base template was declared inside namespace, child - not. And there was a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after fixing some minor issues, your code compiles fine (using clang 3.3) and produces the required result. here is the fixed code (in one file, but in the order of #include)

```
template<typename T> class Smelter;

template <typename T>
class Forge
{
public:
  long SmeltIt(std::vector<T>& ore)   // must be public; use std::
  {
    long res{};                       // must be initialized (to 0)
    Smelter<T> smelter;  
    for (const auto t : ore)
      res += smelter.smelt(t);
    return res;
  }
};

class Iron {};

template<>
class Smelter<Iron>
{
public:
  long smelt(const Iron& iron)       // must be public
  { return 5; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Iron> ore;             // std::
  Iron iron;
  ore.push_back(iron);
  ore.push_back(iron);
  ore.push_back(iron);
  Forge<Iron> forge;
  std::cout << forge.SmeltIt(ore)    // have to be 15
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I had, and what I described higher (but with fixed errors, thx!). Problem was with namespaces and my blindness, so everything perfectly works.